# Highcharts: Stacked bar chart display categories data, not series

Tags: highcharts

I have two JS associative arrays that look like this:

```
var distroDates = [
{
    name: 'exDate',
    data: [
        '06/25/2013',
        '12/17/2012',
        '06/20/2012',
        '12/19/2011',
        '06/21/2011',
        '12/20/2010',
        '06/21/2010',
        '12/21/2009',
        '06/22/2009',
        '12/22/2008',
        '06/23/2008',
        '12/24/2007',
        '12/21/2006',
        '12/23/2005',
        '12/23/2004',
        '12/22/2003',
        '12/23/2002'
    ]
},
{
    name: 'Record Date',
    data: [
        '06/27/2013',
        '12/19/2012',
        '06/22/2012',
        '12/21/2011',
        '06/23/2011',
        '12/22/2010',
        '06/23/2010',
        '12/23/2009',
        '06/24/2009',
        '12/24/2008',
        '06/25/2008',
        '12/27/2007',
        '12/26/2006',
        '12/28/2005',
        '12/28/2004',
        '12/24/2003',
        '12/26/2002'
    ]
},
{
    name: 'Payable Date',
    data: [
        '07/02/2013',
        '12/24/2012',
        '06/27/2012',
        '12/29/2011',
        '06/27/2011',
        '12/30/2010',
        '06/25/2010',
        '12/31/2009',
        '06/26/2009',
        '12/31/2008',
        '06/27/2008',
        '01/04/2008',
        '12/28/2006',
        '12/30/2005',
        '12/30/2004',
        '01/02/2004',
        '01/02/2003'
    ]
}
]
var distroData = [
{
    name: 'Income',
    data: [
        0.3908,
        0.4948,
        0.2311,
        0.3342,
        0.245,
        0.2213,
        0.19,
        0.1404,
        0.2014,
        0.2266,
        0.2131,
        0.2328,
        0.1288,
        0.0044,
        0.6248,
        0,
        0
    ]
},
{
    name: 'S.T. Capital Gains',
    data: [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
},
{
    name: 'L.T. Capital Gains',
    data: [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
},
{
    name: 'Return on Capital',
    data: [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0.0202,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
}
]
```

The distroData array is used for the series.  The distroDates is used for the categories.  I want the categories to display in the tooltip (rather than the usual series data) and I want the tooltip to update with the category values as I hover over each bar along the x-axis.

The following code accomplished this using Highcharts v2.1.4/Highstock v1.2.5 (both are loaded):

```
            tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var s = '<table class="tooltip distro"><tbody>';
                var chart = this.points[0].series.chart; //get the chart object
                var categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories; //get the categories array
                var index = 0;
                var distroDataPoint;
                while(this.x !== categories[index]){index++;} //compute the index of corr y value in each data arrays
                $.each(distroDates, function(i, categories) { //loop through categories array
                    s += '<tr><td>'+ categories.name +':</td><td>' + categories.data[index] + '</td></tr>'; //use index to peg categories and distro data to series
                    distroDataPoint = '<tr><td>Distribution:</td><td>$' + distroData[0].data[index] + '</td></tr>';
                });
                s += distroDataPoint + '</tbody></table>'
                return s;
            },
            shared: true
        },
```

However, when I upgraded to Highstock 1.3.4 (which includes Highcharts) the while statement locked my browser (FF and Chrome).  The browser gave the familiar "Script is non-responsive" alert I assume because it was caught in an expensive loop.

Any ideas how I can rewrite or substitute the while so that performance is acceptable?

Comment: Can you share this in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use shared tooltip? Just set `tooltip.shared = true` and everything will work fine. See example how to format shared tooltip [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6XPpv/).

Comment: I definitely needed to set that options.  However, what really fixed the performance was moving the code into jsfiddle.  I think the issue lies with the default highcharts options set in our app's code.  See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/dylanmac/LfqLD/9/